# iOS App Invite Notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an iOS app with facebook login.  In the app you can invite your friends using the FBSDKAppInviteDialog.  At the end of this process after setting up the app links and everything, I had some strange behavior I couldn't figure out.  The invites are successfully sent (positive callback delegation method), but the invitee Only sees the notification/invitation from the facebook iOS mobile app. From mobile safari or any desktop web clients, they get no notification at all.  Does anyone know how what determines what platform a user gets notified on?  I have an app domain for the website (with app links) registered, and added to the "website data" field in the [facebook created app link](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/568177226618619/?platform=app-links-host).  Thanks in advance for any advice.  I have scowered the web and have not found anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is an issue with the meta tags on your website with app links. I would use the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and make sure it looks like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="example://applinks" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="12345" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Example App" />
<meta property="og:title" content="example page title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<!-- Other headers -->
</head>
<!-- Other HTML content -->
</html>
</head>
```

Honestly you don't even need to have the website if it's only purpose is for app links, since Facebook handles this for you with their api. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/hosting-api)

All the documentation I could find says the notification will show on the first Facebook platform that the user accesses.

> Your app link URL must contain the proper data and structure in order for App Invites to function.